# Detecting nullability within reified types

Tags: kotlin

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58923487/869736), you can detect if a reified type includes null:

```
inline fun <reified T> isTNullable() = null is T
```

However, I wish to make an even more complex query, which I'm not sure is possible: testing if a reified type `T` is a `Pair` and which, if any, of its components is nullable.  I want a method with the following properties:

```
inline fun <reified T> nullabilityOfPairComponents(): Pair<Boolean, Boolean>?

nullabilityOfPairComponents<Int>() == null
nullabilityOfPairComponents<Pair<Int?, String>> = Pair(true, false)
nullabilityOfPairComponents<Pair<Int?, String?>> = Pair(true, true)
```

Is this possible?  I observe that `KType`s have a nullability component, but it seems that we can only currently retrieve a `KClass`, not a `KType`, from reified types.

Note that we cannot use tricks like `<reified A, reified B, T : Pair<A, B>>`, because this method must accept arbitrary types (the `<Int>` example).

Comment: "but it seems that we can only currently retrieve a KClass, not a KType, from reified types" https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With experimental APIs, it is certainly possible:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T : Any> nullabilityOfPairComponents(t: T): Pair<Boolean, Boolean>? {
  if (T::class.java != Pair::class.java) return null
  val (t1, t2) = typeOf<T>().arguments
  return Pair(
      t1.type!!.isMarkedNullable,
      t2.type!!.isMarkedNullable
  )
}
```

This depends on the experimental `typeOf` method.